# How to use two apps in one Firebase project for push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have created one project(TravellerProject) in Firebase developer console... i've added an Android App(UserApp) and i've taken *Server key* and i used that server key for push notification in to my App Admin site... now i have a new App(DriverApp) related to first App(UserApp)... both are same domain so i didn't created new Project, instead i added one more App in the same  project(TravellerProject) with different SHA-1 key... and i was trying to use push notifications for new App(DriverApp). can i use same *Server Key* for both or i've to create new Server key...?

Comment: same key for both will do

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple. Just open firebase account and select the app in which you want to add another app. you will see the the option to add another app on the top right corner. just click and pass your package name and all the details of your new app. 
Now you can use it in both the app. I have included [image: screenshot]

Comment: i've done already like that only... and i created two apps... i solved my issue... Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

yes, **Server Key** is working... in my case problem with *com.google.firebase:firebase-core* version... previously i am using *com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0* so refresh token was not generating... now i've changed to *com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2*... and now it's working... Thank you

[image]